# Mimic an IR remote Volume Button

Tags: vb.net, winforms, button, timer

I have a small media player application I've programmed which works really well.
I've even managed an on screen remote control (obviously just a Form with Buttons made to look like a virtual remote control) and yes I've also integrated an Arduino to be able to use a real remote control, but forget the Arduino remote control just for now my question is about the Virtual remote control I'm trying to build.

Programming a Button is quite  elementary: it's one of the first things we learn in Vb.net, but that's just in a single click scenario.
If I look at a real TV remote, I can either click (most common with volume buttons) the volume up or down and the response is either that the volume goes up or down by one unit, or I can hold the same button down and it repeats the process changing the unit several times up or down depending on how long before I release the button again.

How would I achieve this?

I have tried googling this but everything I get back as a search result talks about a physical mouse button as apposed to what I need which is a Button control.

Answer (score 1):

An example of an UserControl that provides the functionality of Up/Down spin buttons.
It uses two standard Buttons, a Label and a Timer.

To set it up, add a new UserControl to the Project:

- Set its BackColor to `Color.Transparent`
- Add two Buttons, select both and add event handlers to the MouseDown, MouseUp, KeyDown and KeyUp events (selecting both, you'll add 4 method)
- Two Unicode chars (`U+25B2` and `U+25BC`) are used to show the arrows. Setup the Buttons' Font size and Color as required (the sample UC uses `Segoe UI` as Font).

  - Anchor the upper Button to Left/Top/Right
  - Anchor the lower Button to Left/Bottom/Right
  - Anchor the Label to Left/Right
- A Timer is created in the UC constructor, its `Interval` value set to `300`. This value represents the initial speed of the increment when a mouse Button or keyboard key is held down. It's decremented each time the Timer ticks until it reaches a threshold defined by the UC's **`Speed`** public property (which is internally limited to the (1:10) range).
- The maximum and minimum increment are defined by the UC's **`Min`** and **`Max`** public properties
- The **`Value`** public property gets or sets the current increment.

The Timer is started when a Mouse Button or a Keyboard key are pressed and stopped when they're released. When the **`Timer.Tick`** event is raised, the **`Timer.Interval`** is decreased by `25ms` until the max **`Speed`** value is reached. Since the initial value is set to **`300ms`** and the maximum `Speed` is limited to **`10`**, the minimum Interval value is `50ms`, which is close to the `System.Windows.Form.Timer` *official* resolution.
The minimum Interval needs to be considered if these values are changed, to avoid overlapping `Tick` events.

This is how it works:

[image: SpinButtons UserControl]

---

```
Imports System.Windows.Forms

Public Class SpinButtons
    Private buttonsTimer As Timer = Nothing
    Private timerThrottle As Integer = 0
    Private timerIncrement As Integer = 0
    Private m_Speed As Integer = 10
    Private m_Value As Integer = 0

    Public Sub New()
        InitializeComponent()
        Me.components = New System.ComponentModel.Container()
        buttonsTimer = New Timer With {.Interval = 300}
        Me.components.Add(buttonsTimer)
    End Sub

    Public Property Max As Integer = 100
    Public Property Min As Integer = 0

    Public Property Speed As Integer
        Get
            Return m_Speed
        End Get
        Set
            m_Speed = Math.Max(Math.Min(Value, 10), 1)
        End Set
    End Property

    Public Property Value As Integer
        Get
            Return m_Value
        End Get
        Set
            m_Value = Value
            SetIncrementValue()
        End Set
    End Property

    Private Sub buttonsTimer_Tick(sender As Object, e As EventArgs)
        SetIncrementValue()
        If timerThrottle <= m_Speed Then
            timerThrottle += 1
            buttonsTimer.Interval -= 25
        End If
    End Sub

    Private Sub btnUp_MouseDown(sender As Object, e As MouseEventArgs) Handles btnUp.MouseDown, btnDown.MouseDown
        ButtonPressed(DirectCast(sender, Button))
        SetIncrementValue()
    End Sub

    Private Sub btnUp_MouseUp(sender As Object, e As MouseEventArgs) Handles btnUp.MouseUp, btnDown.MouseUp
        ButtonReleased(DirectCast(sender, Button))
    End Sub

    Private Sub btnUp_KeyDown(sender As Object, e As KeyEventArgs) Handles btnUp.KeyDown, btnDown.KeyDown
        ButtonPressed(DirectCast(sender, Button))
        SetIncrementValue()
    End Sub

    Private Sub btnUp_KeyUp(sender As Object, e As KeyEventArgs) Handles btnUp.KeyUp, btnDown.KeyUp
        ButtonReleased(DirectCast(sender, Button))
    End Sub

    Private Sub SetIncrementValue()
        m_Value += timerIncrement
        m_Value = Math.Max(Math.Min(m_Value, Max), Min)
        lblCounter.Text = m_Value.ToString()
    End Sub

    Private Sub ButtonPressed(btn As Button)
        btn.ForeColor = Color.LawnGreen
        timerIncrement = If(btn Is btnUp, 1, -1)
        buttonsTimer.Enabled = True
    End Sub

    Private Sub ButtonReleased(btn As Button)
        buttonsTimer.Enabled = False
        buttonsTimer.Interval = 300
        timerThrottle = 0
        timerIncrement = 0
        btn.ForeColor = Color.White
    End Sub

    Protected Overrides Sub OnFontChanged(e As EventArgs)
        MyBase.OnFontChanged(e)
        Me.btnUp.Font = Me.Font
        Me.btnDown.Font = Me.Font
    End Sub
    Protected Overrides Sub OnResize(e As EventArgs)
        MyBase.OnResize(e)
        Me.MinimumSize = New Size(CInt(Me.Font.Size * 2), Me.btnUp.Height + Me.btnDown.Height + lblCounter.Height)
    End Sub
End Class
```